# Jquery autocomplete multiple textbox

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to create 3 text box the first one will ask for name so when the name is selected through the autocomplete jquery the other two fields are automatically completed through database using jquery .... so can anyone tell me how can i solve this problem

Comment: What have you done so far, and what specific problem do you have?

Comment: I have created 3 text boxes 1. Name 2.contact 3.address and i want that if user select a name by typing some letters through jquery then the two other text boxes must be filled with their corresponding values through database

Answer (score 0):

You can try [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) with "City / State Selection" Example

Comment: You have code example with 2 textbox. Why can you code with 3 textbox? Do you want me code all for you ?